# retrieve only first occurrence of element with contain

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I retrieve only the first occurrence of the name John in case there are duplicates?

```
    @foreach (var c in Model.Select(s => s.Name))
    {
        if (c.Contains("John"))
            {
              ...
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@{ var name = Model.Select(s => s.Name).FirstOrDefault(n => n.Contains("John"));}

@if (name != null)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the LINQ extension method `FirstOrDefault`.